# Error creating API controller with ASP.NET Core 5 and Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, connection-string, asp.net-core-5.0, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I get an error when I create API controller with scaffold on ASP.NET Core 5 with Entity Framework Core; the message says "Parameter connection string can't be null".

My connection settings in `appSettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "connectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":"Data Source=DESKTOP-THJSEM4;Initial,Catalog=M_VPSA_V3;Integrated Security=True"
  }}
```

[Error compiler on creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2meWV.png)

Configuration in class `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddDbContext<M_VPSA_V3Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConection")));

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API_MOBEXX", Version = "v1" });
            });
}
```

And stack trace from error:

> Finding the generator 'controller'...
> Running the generator 'controller'...
> Attempting to compile the application in memory.
>
> Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Boletum'
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

```
> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)  
> at API_MOBEXX.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
>
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') 
>    
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)  
> at   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__17`1.<AddCoreServices>b__17_1(IServiceProvider p)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices[T](IServiceProvider provider)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes()  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextActivator.CreateInstance(Type contextType, Assembly startupAssembly, IOperationReportHandler reportHandler, String[] args)  
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextActivator.CreateInstance(Type contextType, Assembly startupAssembly, IOperationReportHandler reportHandler)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkModelProcessor.TryCreateContextUsingAppCode(Type dbContextType, Type startupType)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()  
> at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

your appsettings is wrong:

adding 's' to sectiong connectionString

```
"connectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":"Data Source=DESKTOP-THJSEM4;Initial,Catalog=M_VPSA_V3;Integrated Security=True"
  }}
```

[Edit]
Use wrong string name in method getconnection. DefaultConection lack of one n

Comment: Thanks but I tried placing it this way and I get the same error.       ==>   "connectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":"Data Source=DESKTOP-THJSEM4;Initial,Catalog=M_VPSA_V3;Integrated Security=True"
  }

Comment: Are you sure you write correct DefaultConection? Because in your code I see one less n

Comment: Yes!!! that was the problem !!! Thank you very much ... I have been reuniting for two days and that was the problem. THANK YOU!!